# Magic square with equal sums on rows, columns and diagonals

Tags: magic-square

[image: Question].

*Transcription:*

```
In a given magic square, if the sum of number in each row
and each column and both of the main diagonals are equal,
then the value of x is:

1) 10
2) 12
3) 8
4) 15
```

Source:[INTSO Grade 3](http://www.intso.co.in/pdf/3rdMTSO.pdf)

Comment: Is this question from an ongoing competition? If not, credit the source.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is:

> 12.

Right So, here's an image

> [image]

Here's a description of the working:

> As sum of all rows,columns and main diagonals are equal.
>  $$13+y+d=15+y+5 \implies d=7$$
>  $$ b+15+d=x+y+b \implies x+y=22$$ (using d=7)
>  $$ 13+5+x=15+5+y \implies x-y=2 $$
>  So, solving the two equations in x and y, we get x=12 and y=10